# QR code is generated but not showing on page

Tags: php, codeigniter, qr-code

[image]

**VIEW (HTML)**

```
<tbody> 
  <?php foreach ($order_data as $key => $value): ?>
    <tr>
      <td> <?php echo $value['id'] ?> </td>
      <td> <img src="<?php echo base_url('z_ex/v_1/render/generateQRcode/'.$value['id']) ?>" alt="..."> </td>
    </tr>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
```

**Controller (SCRIPT)**

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access 
 allowed');
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);
 error_reporting(E_ALL);

 require "vendor/autoload.php";
 use Endroid\QrCode\QrCode;

class Render extends Admin_Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->not_logged_in();
    }

    public function index(){

        if (!in_array('viewOrder', $this->permission)) {
            redirect('z_ex/v_1/dashboard', 'refresh');
        }

        $data = $this->model_orders->getOrdersTrackingNum();
        $this->data['data'] = $data;
        $this->load->view('render', $this->data);

    }

    public function generateQRcode($bill_no = 123456) {

        $qr = new QrCode("HEy there");
        header('Content-Type: '.$qr->getContentType());
        echo $qr->writeString();

    }
}
```

I am using Endroid QrCode package for generating QR code and it shows this way (as on the picture), **NO ERROR, NO WARNING, Just a black background with a small white square.**, I changed the output to be written on a file and save it, **IT WORKS**. But i do not want to save it, I just want it to be displayed when I call it dynamically and that is it. The Header is set to image/png as you can see from the right side of the image.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @DarkBee I updated the question, can you please check it

Comment: @CBroe I am sorry, could know how to demonstrate the output

Comment: What do you see, when you check the preview & response tabs for that request in your browser dev tools?

Comment: @CBroe response tab is empty, but preview gives a string " Image from localhost/render/generateQRcode ", but no image is displayed. Only text

Comment: Which version of `QRcode` are you using?

Comment: @DarkBee Endroid/qr-code 3.9.6

Comment: @DarkBee Thanks, but still not working. Now it says method "create()" is not defined, I checked the files they are different from the ones on GITHUB documentation. I installed it with composer and followed its documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally fixed the problem by adding `data:image/png;base64` to the `src` of `img tag` in the HTML and it worked.

Thanks to everybody.